# How to merge two single column files together?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, merge

I have two files and they have the same number of lines.

```
File A:
USA
UK
MEXICO
CHINA
RUSSIA

File B:
Washington DC
London
MEXICO CITY
BEIJING
MOSCOW
```

How can I merge these two files together using unix commands to make a file like this:

```
Result File:
USA Washington DC
UK London
MEXICO MEXICO CITY
CHINA BEIJING
RUSSIA MOSCOW
```

These two columns could be separated by tab or comma or any other thing?

Thank you for any suggestions?

Comment: StackOverflow is around to help you sort out problems in your implementation. Please, show us samples of what you've attempted and we can help you towards the right direction.

Comment: I tried to summarize my problem so giving out this example. I apologize if this make you feel unhappy.

Comment: Second result in google when searching `merge two files unix` http://superuser.com/questions/565212/how-to-combine-contents-of-2-txt-files-in-unix-i-know-the-cat-command-can-do-th

Answer (score 1):

You can try `paste`

```
$ paste file1 file2
USA Washington DC
UK  London
MEXICO  MEXICO CITY
CHINA   BEIJING
RUSSIA  MOSCOW
```

Comment: My `paste` gets some different spacing in the output.  Both column is align. What version do you use. I have `paste (GNU coreutils) 8.21`

Comment: @Jotne SO did the formating :P. Test on `paste (GNU coreutils) 8.23` gave me 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `paste`, but this `awk` will do to:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR],$0}' fileA fileB
USA Washington DC
UK London
MEXICO MEXICO CITY
CHINA BEIJING
RUSSIA MOSCOW
```